# Login PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando un login en el cual tengo un problema, en la base de datos tengo actualmente 3 usuarios los cuales son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al momento de hacer en PHP tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<?php
    
    require "bd/conexion.php";
    
    session_start();
    
    if($_POST){
        
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        
        $sql = "SELECT id, password, nombre, tipo_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario'";
        //echo $sql;
        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
        $num = $resultado->num_rows;
        
        if($num>0){
            $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
            $password_bd = $row['password'];
            
            $pass_c = $password;
            
            if($password_bd == $pass_c){
                
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
                $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $row['tipo_usuario'];
                
                echo "Conexion Exitosa";
                header("Location: home.php");
                
            } else {
            
            echo "La contraseña no coincide";
            
            }
            
            
            } else {
            echo "NO existe usuario";
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    
?>
```

la clave para todos los usuarios para efecto de prueba les he puesto 123456, sin embargo no me ingresa siempre me sale que las contraseñas no coinciden

adicional este es el codigo que uso para ingresar un nuevo usuario

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');

if (isset($_POST['save_adm'])) 
{
    $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $tipo_usuario=$_POST['tipo_usuario'];
  $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios    (usuario,password,nombre,tipo_usuario) VALUES ('$usuario', '".md5($password)."', '$nombre', '$tipo_usuario')";
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
  if(!$result) {
    die("Query Failed.");
  }

  $_SESSION['message'] = 'Usuario Registrado Correctamente';
  $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'success';
  header('Location: ../home.php');

}

?>
```

Pero no encuentro la razon por la cual no ingresa, soy algo nuevo para PHP

Comment: Fijate que le cambiela clave asi en duro desde MySQL y y pude ingresar, pero ahorita intente ingresar un nuevo usuario y me salio el mismo error, sera algun problema al momento de ingresar el usuario?

Comment: Cuando creas el usuario encriptas la contraseña con md5, pero cuando verificas después de obtener el usuario estas comparado la contraseña de DB encriptada con la contraseña "pass_c" que supongo esta en texto plano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa amigo es que al realizar la consulta del usuario comparas la contraseña de la bd que esta encriptada con md5 contra la que ingresa el usuario.

Obviamente el usuario la ingresa en texto plano, lo que debes hacer es primero convertir el texto plano a MD5 y después compararlo contra la base de datos.

Te sugiero uses [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php) y [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php) ya que tanto md5 como sha1 no son seguros.

Un ejemplo para usar password_hash() y password_verify() es:

Register.php

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');

if (isset($_POST['save_adm'])) 
{
    $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $contrasena_guardar_BD = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $tipo_usuario=$_POST['tipo_usuario'];
  $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios    (usuario,password,nombre,tipo_usuario) VALUES ('$usuario', '$contrasena_guardar_BD', '$nombre', '$tipo_usuario')";
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
  if(!$result) {
    die("Query Failed.");
  }

  $_SESSION['message'] = 'Usuario Registrado Correctamente';
  $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'success';
  header('Location: ../home.php');

}

?>
```

Debes tener en cuenta que al usar PASSWORD_DEFAULT debes tener un campo en tu base de datos que pueda almacenar muchos caracteres.

> PASSWORD_DEFAULT - Usar el algoritmo bcrypt (predeterminado a partir
> de PHP 5.5.0). Observe que esta constante está diseñada para cambiar
> siempre que se añada un algoritmo nuevo y más fuerte a PHP. Por esta
> razón, la longitud del resultado de usar este identificador puede
> cambiar con el tiempo. Por lo tanto, se recomienda almacenar el
> resultado en una columna de una base de datos que pueda ampliarse a
> más de 60 caracteres (255 caracteres sería una buena elección).

Ahora en tu login podría ser algo como esto:

```
<?php
    
    require "bd/conexion.php";
    
    session_start();
    
    if($_POST){
        
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        
        $sql = "SELECT id, password, nombre, tipo_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario'";
        //echo $sql;
        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
        $num = $resultado->num_rows;
        
        if($num>0){
            $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
            $password_bd = $row['password'];
            
           if (password_verify($password, $password_bd)) {
                
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
                $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $row['tipo_usuario'];
                
                echo "Conexion Exitosa";
                header("Location: home.php");
                
            } else {
            
            echo "La contraseña no coincide";
            
            }
```

Igual cabe aclarar que soy algo nuevo en esto, pero si tengo algun error espero algún compañero con más experiencia nos heche un cable, pero mas o menos así fue como lo integre yo y funciono.

Comment: Buenas, esto parece más comentario que respuesta, una respuesta añade y explica los errores, además de mostrar el código correcto. Por favor edita tu respuesta para que sea válida.

Comment: @Excorpion, pensé que lo había hecho como comentario no como respuesta, lamento la confusión pero he agregado el código y los comentarios pertinentes para cumplir con las reglas, de nuevo lo siento.